# Invalid array assignment while shifting struct element

Tags: c

I have to "delete" some elements from struct. For example let it be years.
So i should find them in my struct, shift them and display new struct without them.

Our professor said, that we should use pointers to structs. And i don't get it. I mean from my point of view structs works as arrays but with some specifications.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if ( yr == (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear) {
        for (i = pos; i < n - 1; i++)
        (mvbs+i ) -> udk = (mvbs+i+1) -> udk; //int
        (mvbs+i) -> name = (mvbs+i+1) -> name; //char
        (mvbs+i) -> genre = (mvbs+i+1) -> genre;//char
        (mvbs+i) -> creator = (mvbs+i+1) -> creator;//char
        (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear = (mvbs+i+1) -> releaseYear;//int
        (dtbs+i) -> day = (dtbs+i+1) -> day;//int
        (dtbs+i) -> month = (dtbs+i+1) -> month;//int
        (dtbs+i) -> year = (dtbs+i+1) -> year;//int
    }
}
```

I guess it should shift data to "deleted" space but I get invalid array assignment with all char stuff.

Here are my `struct`s

```
struct date { 
    int day; 
    int month; 
    int year; 
}; 

date datebase[100], *dtbs=datebase; 

struct movies { 
    int udk; 
    char name[10]; 
    char genre[10]; 
    char creator[10];
    int releaseYear; 
    struct date movieRental; 
}; 

movies mooviebase[100], *mvbs=mooviebase;
```

Comment: could you please provide the definition of your struct ? what is mbvs ? what is pos ?

Comment: My fault. Here:
``````
 struct date
 {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
 };
 date datebase[100], *dtbs=datebase;
 
 struct movies
 {
  int udk;
  char name[10];
  char genre[10];
  char creator[10];
  int releaseYear;
  struct date movieRental;
 };
 movies mooviebase[100], *mvbs=mooviebase;
````

Comment: You can edit your code for readability

Comment: Please edit the code in your question rather than providing it in the comments. Please also make it a fully compilable program.

Comment: The variable definitions are wrong, should be `struct date datebase[100], *dtbs=datebase; ` and `struct movies mooviebase[100], *mvbs=mooviebase;`. The keyword `struct` is missing.

Comment: One cannot delete an element from a struct, this makes no sense. Posted code doesn't seem to attempt deleting a "year" element from a struct. It looks like it tries to delete the "i"th element from an array of structs

Comment: @n.m. your deleted answer looked good - it seems that OP is shuffling array elements down every member by member, but with some syntax errors (the `struct` keyword, the nested `struct` access) and isn't accounting for the "holes" left in the array. There should be a source index and a destination index for the `struct` copies.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes that's what the code seems to be trying to do but the question asks about something entirely different.

Comment: Why aren't you writing `mvbs[i].udk` and alike?

Comment: @umbrella123 you do not like the answer(s), none of them answer to your question  ?

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid array assignment while shifting struct element

Warning if I indent correctly your code it is :

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if ( yr == (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear)
  {
    for (i = pos; i < n - 1; i++)
      (mvbs+i ) -> udk = (mvbs+i+1) -> udk; //int
    (mvbs+i) -> name = (mvbs+i+1) -> name; //char
    (mvbs+i) -> genre = (mvbs+i+1) -> genre;//char
    (mvbs+i) -> creator = (mvbs+i+1) -> creator;//char
    (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear = (mvbs+i+1) -> releaseYear;//int
    (dtbs+i) -> day = (dtbs+i+1) -> day;//int
    (dtbs+i) -> month = (dtbs+i+1) -> month;//int
    (dtbs+i) -> year = (dtbs+i+1) -> year;//int
  }
}
```

but this is not what you want because only *udk* is moved in the loop and for all the other element *k* value *n-1* (I suppose `pos  <= n - 1`) so you do for instance `(mvbs+n-1) -> name = (mvbs+n) -> name`, and *n* being visible the size you go out of the initialized part of the array or may be out of the array.

Of course you missed to add {} to do :

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if ( yr == (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear)
  {
    for (i = pos; i < n - 1; i++) {
      (mvbs+i ) -> udk = (mvbs+i+1) -> udk; //int
      (mvbs+i) -> name = (mvbs+i+1) -> name; //char
      (mvbs+i) -> genre = (mvbs+i+1) -> genre;//char
      (mvbs+i) -> creator = (mvbs+i+1) -> creator;//char
      (mvbs+i) -> releaseYear = (mvbs+i+1) -> releaseYear;//int
      (dtbs+i) -> day = (dtbs+i+1) -> day;//int
      (dtbs+i) -> month = (dtbs+i+1) -> month;//int
      (dtbs+i) -> year = (dtbs+i+1) -> year;//int
    }
  }
}
```

However first what *pos* is ? and because you reuse/modify the variable *i* in the embedded *for* you cannot manage the case where several entries have the same *releaseYear*

Probably the first *for* is supposed to be on *pos* rather than on *i* to be more consistent and to remove the entries *pos* having the search year.

After the embedded *for*  there is one less element so you need to decrease *n*

Note if there are several consecutive entries having the search year you can optimize to bypass them at the same time rather than to do one by one.

The type of the elements are compatible to a direct copy so the code can be simplified to be :

```
pos = 0;

while(pos < n)
{
  if ( yr == (mvbs+pos) -> releaseYear)
  {
    for (i = pos; i < n - 1; i++) {
      *(mvbs+i ) = *(mvbs+i+1)
    }
    n -= 1;
  }
  else
    pos += 1;
}
```

and finally you can use a *memmove* rather than to do the copy by yourself element by element :

```
pos = 0;

while(pos < n)
{
  if ( yr == (mvbs+pos)->releaseYear)
  {
    if (pos == --n)
      /* it was the last entry */
      break;
    memmove(mvbs+pos, mvbs+pos+1, (n-pos)*sizeof(movies));
  }
  else
    pos += 1;
}
```

> Our professor said, that we should use pointers to structs

You already use a pointer because you do not do `mooviebase[pos]` for instance but use *mvbs+offset*, but that pointer never change and you need the additional offset, so your pointer is not useful, you can do for instance :

```
movies * ptr = mooviebase;
movies * sup = mooviebase + n;

while (ptr != sup)
{
  if (yr == ptr->releaseYear)
  {
    if (ptr == --sup)
      /* it was the last entry */
      break;
    memmove(ptr, ptr+1, (sup - ptr)*sizeof(movies));
  }
  else
    ptr += 1;
}
```

Comment: and you too: `mvbs[i] = mvbs[i + 1]` :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala 1) that changes nothing, 2) I follow the way to write of the OP to help him to see the errors comparing his code and mine, 3) the goal for the OP is to move to the use of pointer , so ... ;-)

Comment: Mind you that `[]` operator is *only* defined for pointers, about time we teach the people that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala c'mon, using pointer means to do `*mvbs` and `++mvbs` for instance, do you really suppose I am stupid ? I hope not ^^ Did you read the end of my answer ?

Comment: I am not sure if you're sarcastic or not, let me reiterate - `foo[i]` operator requires a pointer as one of the operands, so using `*(foo + bar)` isn't "more using pointers", it just looks awkward.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are blocked in a wrong loop, please reboot